# Sending same HTTP request concurrently in Jmter

Tags: jmeter

We have a test scenario where we want to upload a file in a multithread manner i.e., concurrently upload a file based on thread count.

The transaction involves a couple of HTTP requests where only the upload HTTP request needs to be triggered simultaneously (not in a loop).

Throughput controller does not help since it again sends the HTTP request one after the other.

Synchronizing Timer does not work either since the same HTTP request needs to be triggered concurrently for a single Thread.

Comment: `same HTTP request needs to be triggered concurrently for a single Thread` -- that's not how JMeter works. Why do you need to have multiple requests in one thread? What are you trying to solve by that? For example if you need all threads to use the same authentication, there's solution for that. But if you want 1 thread to run multiple HTTP requests in parallel, you need to write your own sampler... or use a different tool than JMeter

Comment: My scenario is that a single user logs in and uploads a folder containing multiple files. Our application code works in a way where multiple files will be uploaded in parallel based on thread count set in the code. We want to simulate variable thread count scenarios for a single request similar to our application.

Comment: Single user doesn't necessarily convert to 1 thread in JMeter. In your case what you have to do is to have JMeter thread per file you want to upload. While "user logs in" operation is done once, and authentication is shared among all the threads.That way you can either use Throughput controller or Synchronizing Timer. But you *cannot* trigger HTTP request concurrently for 1 thread, it's against JMeter architecture.